# NSURLConnection and Images Download Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I have a JSON feed with about 350 records. I used NSURLConnection to download them upon launch from the feed. Each item in the feed has a URL to an image. I need download an image thumbnail for many of those feeds. It is very similar to what a twitter client would do (since I also display them in a table view). When I use normal UIImage = [UIImage alloc] initWithData etc... It will take forever. Also, since the table cells load as I scroll, scrolling down while loading the images would cause the app to load the images and terrible user experience (as well as lag).

What are some alternatives that you suggest? I am using NSURLConnection in the application:didFinishLaunch. Should I implement it one more time in the view controller of that table view class?

Any suggestions / guidance is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: you should accept answers, people'll be more willing to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the images URL, you can use `TCWebImageView` to download and **cache** (in the file system) the images on demand.

https://github.com/totocaster/TCWebImageView

which is a nice and simple async image component by the way.

EDIT:

Another good library that is worth taking a look is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)'s ASINetworkQueue (which is a nice subclass of NSOperationQueue) and it makes it a very easy and robust way of performing a heavy load (350+ items) download management

EDIT 2:

There is another good solution inside the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) library, which is the [AFImageRequestOperation](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFImageRequestOperation.html) where you can easily use its `UIImageView` category with no need for subclassing or managing the download queue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Async image downloading in order to download images and that will not disturb the flow of other code, while images will download with time. You can take help from  http://code.google.com/p/iphone-lib/wiki/AsyncImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Users are a lot happier with a fast launch.

I would suggest putting the images in you app, the size will probably be reasonable.

Comment: True - but how do Twitter apps manage to keep their app fast then?

Answer (score 0):

You say

> It is very similar to what a twitter
>   client would do

and

> Also, since the table cells load as I
>   scroll, scrolling down while loading
>   the images would cause the app to load
>   the images and terrible user
>   experience (as well as lag).

I have Twitterrific, Twitter and TweetDeck install and this is exactly what they do (ie load images as they become visible when the user scrolls). Obviously each image, if used more than once (as it probably would be in a twitter timeline) would only be downloaded once and cached.

Comment: Yeah.. and? Did I say anything wrong?

Whether it caches or not, that's not the problem. Each cell has a unique logo.

Comment: @Nayefc, hey, no nothing wrong, only you want an app similar to twitter, but you don't think loading images as you scroll would be a good user experience, right? But that is what you must do - that is what the twitter apps do.

Comment: Oh alright - well then I should rephrase my question to, how do Twitter clients do it so efficiently? Just using NSURLConnection properly?

Comment: @Nayefc, ok - having thumbnail images is probably the most import factor. In the twitter app user-images are about 90x90px - as jpegs maybe < 2k each. Lazily loading them asynchronously after the first time they should appear on the screen - they should take no longer than a fraction of a second to appear. This is not going to work for you if your images are 2MB each. NSURLConnection will handle the async download for you.